# Supervisorctl - Refused connection (even after specifying path -c)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord

I can't figure out how to run `supervisorctl` correctly. There is a `supervisord` running on my `Ubuntu 16.04` server.

The `supervisord.conf` path:

```
/home/django/Bedueno/supervisord.conf
```

When I run

```
supervisorctl
```

or

```
supervisorctl -c /home/django/Bedueno/supervisord.conf
```

console returns

```
django@Bedueno-beta-ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01:~$ supervisorctl -c /home/django/Bedueno/supervisord.conf 
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
supervisor> reread
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 575
supervisor>
```

Tried already with `sudo` which didn't help.

Do you know where is the problem?

**supervisord.conf**

```
[program:daphne]
command=/home/django/Bedueno/beduenovenv/bin/daphne Bedueno.asgi:channel_layer --bind 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 ;
directory=/home/django/Bedueno/ ;
autostart=true ;
autorestart=true ;

[program:daphne_worker]
command=/home/django/Bedueno/beduenovenv/bin/python manage.py runworker ;
directory=/home/django/Bedueno/ ;
autostart=true ;
autorestart=true ;
[supervisord]
[supervisorctl]
```

**EDIT**

I realised I have two supervisord.pid and supervisord.log files.
Both of them are inside `/tmp/` directory and in `/home/django/Bedueno/` too. `supervisor.sock` is only inside `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: So the conf points to port `8001` and the connection error is based on port `9001`.... seems like an issue to me, right? Be sure you are connecting to the correct port which is listening for the traffic.  So `--bind 0.0.0.0 -p 8001` in config but error states `:9001 refused connection`.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT 8001 is a port fo daphne asgi. 9001 is supervisors port so it can't be the same in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, so from a web browser on the machine is applicable, see if you can access `http://localhost:8001` and also try `http://localhost:9001`. See if you can telnet into that port and confirm it's listening and use `netstat` as well to confirm the expected ports are listening on the server. I'm not an Linux expert yet so I was just pointing out the obvious from what I see in the detail you provided. I would test to confirm that the "expected" port is listening to start with next I suppose.

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 9001 returns this: Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
and telnet 127.0.0.1 8001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Look over `netstat -ano` and see if you see any processes listening on those ports from the **Local Address** column from the **
Active Internet connections (servers and established)** section. You should see `<IP Address>:<port>` in there somewhere so if it's not listening the something is not correct I would think like the server service is not running perhaps.

Comment: There is nothing with port 9001. Tried also sudo netstat | grep 9001 which returned nothing.

Comment: Isn't the `[supervisorctl]` section and perhaps the `[supervisord]` sections of the **supervisord.conf** file missing some parameters? Look over those sections per this here: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html and also read over http://supervisord.org/running.html if needed to just to ensure you don't see anything there that looks obvious. I think the configuration parameters are missing and maybe that's why it is not starting. Consider putting the logging level to trace or debug mode per that first link and looking over the logs when you try to start it.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the http method then be sure to check the following:

1. Make sure `supervisord` is running
2. Have these enabled (uncommented) in `supervisord.conf` file:
   a)

   ```
   [inet_http_server]         
   port=127.0.0.1:9001
   ```

   b)

   ```
   [supervisorctl]
   serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
   ```

   c)

   ```
   [rpcinterface:supervisor]
   supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
   ```

**Note:** The host and port of the inet server and the one which supervisorctl is trying to connect to should be the same.